# Jetbrains Rider - Remote build xamarin ios library

Tags: ios, xamarin, rider

I'm having trouble to build and deploy my Xamarin iOS project.
If I'm using nuget dependencies, everything works fine but when I use project dependencies containing xamarin ios class library I cannot build my project.
Error is like:
-Type or namespace XY missing, maybe an assambly is missing-

I think rider does not build my class library on the remote server and so it is not added as project reference ty my app-project. Any suggestions how to solve this?
(Projekt is building and deploying fine in Visual Studio 2019)

Edit:
I use a project dependency to another project in my solution, which is a xamarin iOS class library.
This is the exact error (sorry, it's german, first line is like: Compiling using PATH_TO_ROSLYN, second line is the error, meaning: Type- or NamespaceName TestClass2 not found -> Maybe an Assemblyreference is missing)

```
 0>Freigegebene Kompilierung mit dem Compiler aus dem Verzeichnis wird verwendet: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn
 0>C:\repos\MyApp\TestClass.cs(21,40): Error CS0234 : Der Typ- oder Namespacename "TestClass2" ist im Namespace "MyApp" nicht vorhanden. (Möglicherweise fehlt ein Assemblyverweis.)
```

Building the xamarin ios class library with "Rebuild selected project" shows the message:

```
Xamarin.Messaging.Build.targets(95, 3): [VSX1000] The connection to the Mac Server with Address='' and User='' couldn't be established. The project 'ClassLibraryProject' will continue building offline
```

Think this is what's happening when I try to deploy, too. -> Target configuration is not shared to the project-dependency.

Comment: Is this an SDK style project? If not, have you recently downgraded Xamarin versions?

Comment: @EthanDevelops it is a non SDK-Style project. And it is the same xamarin version I use in VS, which was not up- or downgraded. Rider is a fresh install and iOS build never worked, but it works fine in VS.

Comment: Could you enable 'Use ReSharper Build' and try again?

Comment: @EthanDevelops This was enabled already, disabling did not help either.